# Using Dates in If Function

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I need to determine eligibility as per interval dates with the condition of completing 1 year based on the current date

for instance :

Year 2021 Start Date 1-Mar 2020 competing 1 year in 1-Mar 2021 --> "Eligible"

After the date 1-Mar 2022 the status will be --> "Not Eligible" for the year 2021 and "Eligible" for the year 2022 and so on.

Below the formula I used

```
=IF(MONTH(TODAY())>=DATE(2020,MONTH(G3),DAY(G3)),"Eligible","Not Eligible")
```

Pic from Excel

[image]

Comment: In your image why 20-May-2006 is `Not Eligible` for **2022 Accural**? Why not it is eligible?

Comment: Because the month May- 2022 is yet to come , I’m fine with 2023 accrual , the  confusion is in 2021 accrual

Comment: But what about `19-Dec-2011`? In your image it is also showing `Not Eligible`. Can you explain logic behind it.

Comment: The logic is to count 1 year from the hire month  , in the year 2021 and 2022 see in Year 2021 start date is Dec-2020 till Dec-2021 —> “eligible” in other hand “not eligible”for the year 2022 but when Dec-2022 comes it will be “eligible” and “not eligible” for the year 2021